# get qtreewidgetitemiterator values

Tags: python, qtgui, qtreewidgetitem

I am able to display data in a `qtreewidget` form. While reading values ( and after googling ), I find `qTreeWidgetItemIterator` as a way to iterate through all the items.

`iterator = QTreeWidgetItemIterator(self.light_write, QTreeWidgetItemIterator.All)`

where `self.light_write` is `qtreewidget`.

At present above code prints nothing although there is content.

What is the method to loop through all items in a `treewidget` using `QTreeWidgetItemIterator` or if their is any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer but you could do something like this:

```
def iterTreeWidget(treeWidget):
    for index in range(treeWidget.topLevelItemCount()):
        yield treeWidget.topLevelItem(index)

iterator = iterTreeWidget(self.light_write)
```